# Unable to symlink directory with all file contents

Tags: bash, symlink

I want to symlink `locations` to `~/locations`.

So that everything in `locations` appears in `~/locations`:

```bash
 λ tree locations/
locations/
├── adelaide
│   └── config
├── amber
│   └── config
├── austin
│   └── config
├── boston
│   └── config
├── boulder
│   └── config
├── durham
│   └── config
├── jade
│   └── config
├── losangeles
│   └── config
├── minsk
│   └── config
├── newcastle
│   └── config
├── opal
│   └── config
└── pearl
    └── config
```

When I try to symlink them it doesn't do what I expect:

```
 λ ln -s locations/*/* ~/locations
ln: /Users/bob.smith/locations//config: File exists
ln: /Users/bob.smith/locations/config: File exists
ln: /Users/bob.smith/locations//config: File exists
ln: /Users/bob.smith/locations//config: File exists
ln: /Users/bob.smith/locations//config: File exists
ln: /Users/bob.smith/locations/config: File exists
ln: /Users/bob.smith/locations//config: File exists
ln: /Users/bob.smith/locations//config: File exists
ln: /Users/bob.smith/locations//config: File exists
ln: /Users/bob.smith/locations//config: File exists
ln: /Users/bob.smith/locations//config: File exists

tree locations
 λ tree ~/locations/
/Users/bob.smith/locations/
└── config -> locations/Adelaide/config
```

As you can see the dir after `locations` is missing in the output.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what exact effect you're trying to achieve: just a directory symlink, or a "link farm" where symlinks point to individual files?

A symlink is a tiny file which holds a path. When that file is visited during name resolution, that path is substituted in its place. The path may be relative or absolute.

To make a directory symlink, just do this:

```
ln -s locations ~/locations
```

However, this has a problem! It will create a symlink called `locations` in your home directory, such as `/home/yourname/locations`.  The content of that symlink will be the relative path `locations`.  In other words, that symlink will point to itself, creating a useless loop.

You need to give the correct relative path, or else an absolute path, like:

```
ln -sf /absolute/path/to/locations ~/locations
```

If you have a utility called `realpath`, you can do this right inside the parent directory whose child is `locations`:

```
ln -sf "$(realpath locations)" ~/locations
```

`realpath` prints an absolute path for `locations`, in which all symbolic links are resolved; the `$(...)` command substitution syntax substitutes that into the command line. I put quotes around it in case the resulting path contains whitespace that would split it into multiple arguments.

It's possible to mirror a tree of files using symbolic links. There is a utility for that called `lndir` which originated with the XWindow system. Usually if you want `lndir` installed on a GNU/Linux distro, it's packaged together with the X stuff. `lndir` creates an empty directory tree skeleton which mimics the original directory tree, and populates it with symlinks to the corresponding original files.

If you have a tree of files, that you would like to access via a flat directory of symlinks, you have to write a script for that.

Comment: I thought that if I done `ln -s locations ~/locations` then `~/locations` would mirror all dirs and files in `locations`, is my understanding of symlinks incorrect? So if I done `ln -s $PWD/locations ~/locations` would I get my desired outcome?

Comment: what I was trying to do and what I thought symlinks do is that they mirror the linked dir and the files it contains, is that wrong and symlinks don't actually do that?

Comment: I understand "mirror" to be a copy. Symlinks do not copy anything; they link, just like web hyperlinks. When you link to someone's web page, you are not mirroring it. You don't have a copy that stays the same when they make an edit.

Comment: apologies what I meant was is it not possible to symlink a directory and all of its contents to another directory, so that the other directory is linked in a way that if I make a change to the file in the other directory it would make the same change to the file in the directory I symlinked? So far it seems that symlinks only link directories and not their contents.

Comment: No, symlinks are not a change propagating / sync mechanism.  If you symlink a directory, then you have that directory available under a different path, so all the contained files are the same objects.